# Let <table> expand width via CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I'm having a problem with a dynamic table. The columns are set with the right with except for the last ones on the last row.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Na3b/2/) to clarify what I mean.

[image: here's an image]

I know that if I remove this line from `.inhoud` it is "fixed"

```
margin-left: 150px;
```

But that will break the rest of the website.

How can I fix this problem so that the <td> are the same  everywhere. - It's not a problem if it will expand the width of the container.

Comment: you mean width at the end ?

Comment: It would be for the best if you could also include the relevant markup here in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your `.container`, it has a set width of `1170px` which isn't enough to fully contain your table with the provided margins and padding.
You can either increase this width or decrease the set sizes of your cells or remove the following attribute from your <table>

```
.bw_table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that the table is dynamic. So it can be 4 colloms, or 25 ( or even more... ) So i don't think that i can handle it properly...

Comment: I'll handle the problem difrent... ( will open an popup without the default layout... )

Comment: @user3710342 Edited answer to address the further concerns, there's no need to use a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the `table-layout:fixed attribute` from your `bw_table` heres the new fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Na3b/5/)

Comment: With the default `table-layout: auto`, all cells don't have uniform width, width depends on the contents which in this case are of variable size.

Comment: @nit, indeed. The problem is that the still must have fix with / height... That's not the thing when i comment that out: [http://jsfiddle.net/8Na3b/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/8Na3b/7/)